# PPA for Wine and playonlinux for 20.04?

Tags: wine, ppa, playonlinux, adobe

I do have PlayonLinux with Ubuntu 20.04.It does works great with Adobe Photoshop and Adobe illustrator.

I would like to add the PPA for PlayonLinux and Wine.

What id the actual PPA's for both PlayonLinux and Wine ?

I don't understand the PPA for both software tho.

Comment: What makes you think there is a need for PPAs?

Comment: I want to make sure that PlayonLinux and Wine are always updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not really find a reason to add the two below PPAs/repositories to the system.
The PlayOnLinux installed from repository allows user to download and install any (including latest) version of Wine for user-specified wine prefix (virtual C: drive). So there is no need to add system-wide Wine repository to the system IMHO.

But here they are:

- PlayOnLinux

  ```
  wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_cosmic.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install playonlinux
  ```

  Note: the above repository has latest PlayOnLinux 4.3.4 (last modified 24 Dec 2018) and this version is available in the [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=playonlinux), so there is no practical reason to add this repository.
- WineHQ

  ```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
  wget -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
  sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
  ```

  Note: here we follow [official guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) from WineHQ.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment in 20.04(LTS) playonlinux is broken as it requires python2:any (sic!) and it breaks all system. Thus, playonlinux packages aren't the same and I have to take it from third party repo(