# Issue with dependencies when installing Wine in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine

When running the comand: `apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable` I get the following error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.1~focal-1)` I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Remove the upstream Wine sources that you added. Then run `sudo apt update` because your sources changed. Then install the tested, compatible Wine version in the Ubuntu Repositories `sudo apt install wine`. Let Wine know that their 20.04 instructions no longer work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PPA for Wine and playonlinux for 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247377/ppa-for-wine-and-playonlinux-for-20-04)

Comment: No, I get the same error, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install wine from winehq.org on Ubuntu (actually Lubuntu) 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-from-winehq-org-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was very simple, being a beginner I had disabled almost all the options in the panel "software and updates" > "ubuntu software" letting almost no software to be downloaded so this caused the dependencies issues.